# Forced convection and active temperature?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, temperature, computational-physics, convection

I performed anisothermal  CFD computations with large eddy simulation.
Is the use of the temperature as an active scalar relevant when performing a forced convection RANS or LES computation (Ri<0.01), Ri being the Richardson number? If yes, could you explain me why, since forced convection is defined as a state where the fluid motion is not controled by the temperature variations of the fluid?

Could you confirm or correct the following points:

- Temperature equation is solved in both active and passive temperature.
- passive temperature -> no buoyancy effect, no state law -> fluid properties are constant -> no effect on the dynamic of the flow
- active temperature -> buoyancy effect (not necessarly), state law -> fluid properties depends on the temperature -> dynamic of the flow is altered

Thanks for your answer